# How to apply geometric transformation and do test for region intersection

Tags: regions, rotation

### Description

I want to **generate** a number of ellipses, **rotate** each ellipse using random angle, and then **test** each ellipse if it intersects with any other regions within arbitrary geometry.

I can create my ellipses, and rotate each ellipse using random angle. However, the methods I use don't seem to be compatible when used inside [RegionIntersection](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html)

How could I generate, rotate and test the rotated ellipses to check for intersections with other members of the geometric composition?

### Code

```
Module[
  {data,r1, r2},
  (*Variable declaration*)
  data = RandomInteger[{1,100},{100,2}];

  r1[origin_,radius_, angle_]:=GeometricTransformation[Disk[origin,{radius,radius /7}],RotationTransform[angle,origin]];
  r2[origin_,radius_,angle_] :=Rotate[Disk[origin,{radius,radius/7}],angle,origin];

  (*Program*)
  (*Visual Representation*)
  Show[
    Graphics @ {FaceForm @ None, EdgeForm @ Red,r1[data[[1]],2.5,Pi/6]},
    Graphics @ {FaceForm @ None, EdgeForm @ Blue,r2[data[[1]],2.5,Pi/4]},
    Graphics @ {Opacity @ .5,FaceForm @ Gray, Disk[data[[1]],1]},
    Axis-> True,
    Frame-> True
  ]
]
```

Following are the lines which would crash my code due to ,what I suspect, argument incompatibility

```
(*Intersection [Fail]*)
RegionIntersection[r1,Disk[data[[1]],1]],
RegionIntersection[r2,Disk[data[[1]],1]]
```

Comment: Try [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion.html) instead of [`GeometricTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransformation.html)

Comment: @CarlWoll, thank you for your reply. I think the method works. I am happy to accept it as an answer if you'd like to post one below?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that [`GeometricTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransformation.html) doesn't produce an object that is [`RegionQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionQ.html):

```
GeometricTransformation[
    Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 2}],
    RotationTransform[Pi/2, {0, 0}]
] //RegionQ
```

False

Instead of [`GeometricTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransformation.html), you should use [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion.html):

```
r1 = TransformedRegion[
    Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 2}],
    RotationTransform[Pi/2, {0, 0}]
];
r1 //RegionQ
```

True

Using [`RegionIntersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html) with `r1`:

```
int = RegionIntersection[r1, Disk[{1, 1}, 1]];
DiscretizeRegion[int]
RegionMeasure[int]//N
```

[image]

1.20138

Comment: Yeah I figured it doesn't return `True` when tested with `RegionQ` hence the incompatibility error. I was unaware of `TransformedRegion` function. Thank you for providing an answer to my question. I learned something new :) (y)

Comment: But this is all a little broken. `GeometricTransformation` can (and should, where possible) produce `RegionQ` objects. For example, `Normal@GeometricTransformation[Cylinder[], ScalingTransform[{2, 2, 2}]]`. But this does not work properly in 2D (reported bug).